# plotly px.scatter_3d marker size

Tags: python, plotly, size, marker, scatter3d

I have a dataframe `df`:

```
              x         y         z  ... colours marker_size  marker_opacity
test1  0.118709  0.219099 -0.024387  ...     red         100             0.5
test2 -0.344873 -0.401508  0.169995  ...    blue         100             0.5
test3 -0.226923  0.021078  0.400358  ...     red         100             0.5
test4  0.085421  0.098442 -0.588749  ...  purple         100             0.5
test5  0.367666  0.062889  0.042783  ...   green         100             0.5
```

I am trying to plot this with plotly like so:

```
fig = px.scatter_3d(df, 
                    x='x', y='y', z = 'z', 
                    color='labels', 
                    hover_name = df.index, 
                    opacity = 0.5, 
                    size = 'marker_size')   
fig.write_html(file_name)
```

When I open `file_name`, everything is fine, but my points are too big.  When I alter the `'marker_size'` column of my `df`, nothing changes (I have tried 0.1, 1, 10, 100...).

**Why is this?**

I have also tried:

Param:

`size = 1`:

Result:

`ValueError: Value of 'size' is not the name of a column in 'data_frame'. Expected one of ['x', 'y', 'z', 'labels', 'colours', 'marker_size', 'marker_opacity'] but received: 1`

Param:

`size = [1]*len(df)`:

Result:
No difference to using the `'marker_size'` `df` column

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're looking to increase the marker size of *all* traces, just use:

```
fig.update_traces(marker_size = 12)
```

[image]

#### Details:

The `size` attribute of `px.scatter_3d` isn't there to let you specify the size of your markers *directly*. But rather to let you add a fourth dimension to your scatter plot representing the varying size of another variable.

> ```
> size: str or int or Series or array-like
>     Either a name of a column in `data_frame`, or a pandas Series or
>     array_like object. Values from this column or array_like are used to
>     assign mark sizes.
> ```

The reason why changing the value from `1` to `10` or `100` is that you seem to have been changing *all* the values in `df['marker_size']` at the same time:

[image]

In order for such an assignment to have effect, you would need to have a *variable* and not a *constant* in `df['marker_size']`. You can take a closer look at how these things work through this snippet:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()

fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width', z='petal_width',
              color='species',
              size = 'petal_length'
                   )

fig.show()
```

[image]

Here you can see that the `size` attribute works as intended, since your markers will have varying sizes as defined by `df['petal_length]`:

[image]

Comment: Ah perfect, thanks very much!

Comment: Can't possibly tell u how much that line helped me!